# Combine 3 dataframe columns into 1 with priority while avoiding apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have 3 different columns

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3
 0    a        1       NaN
 1   NaN       3        4
 2    b        6        7
 3   NaN      NaN       7
```

and I want to create 1 final column that would take first value that isn't NA, resulting in:

```
   Column1
 0    a
 1    3
 2    b
 3    7
```

I would usually do this with custom apply function:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ...)
```

I need to do this for many different cases with millions of rows and this becomes very slow. Are  there any operations that would take advantage of vectorization to make this faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back filling missing values and select first column by `[]` for one column `DataFrame` or without for `Series`:

```
df1 = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, [0]]

s = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Comment: You can chain it in one go : ``df.ffill(axis=1).bfill(axis=1).iloc(axis=1)[0]``

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pd.fillna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for this, as below:

```
df['Column1'].fillna(df['Column2']).fillna(df['Column3'])
```

output:

```
0    a
1    3
2    b
3    7
```

For more than 3 columns, this can be placed in a for loop as below, with `new_col` being your output:

```
new_col = df['Column1']
for col in df.columns:
    new_col = new_col.fillna(df[col])
```